# Let A be a cone of radius R and height H, and let C be a right circular cylinder inscribed in A with radius r and height h

Tags: calculus

Find a formula for the surface area of C (excluding the top and the bottom disk). I used ratio to of radius to height to get

$$r=\frac RH h$$

and hence surface area of C to be

$$ 2\pi Rh^2/H$$

The next part then ask us to find the maximum surface area of C in terms of H and R,i tried to differentiate wrt to h but got h=0 instead?

Can anybody check if i did anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\frac{H-h}{r}=\frac{h}{R-r}$$ you can solve this equation for $h$ or $r$ to compute $$M=2\pi r h$$ so we get
$$M=\frac{2\pi r(HR-rH)}{R}$$ a function in $r$

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in applying the ratios to radii and  heights. Note that $h$ is the height of the cylinder, not the height of the small cone. So, you need to replace $h$ with $H-h$ in your calculation to get the radius

$$r=\frac RH (H—h)$$

And, then, the area is

$$A=2\pi rh= \frac{2\pi(H-h)hR}{H}$$

After taking the derivative and set it to zero, you should get

$$h=\frac 12 H$$

for the maximum area of $\frac \pi2 RH$.